# How to set and image to a button using a storyboard default image?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm building a custom checkbox in a class. But I want to use one of the images that are built into Xcode such as in storyboard. if you select the button and select one of the prebuilt images. What I have:
[image]

This will call an image in the assets folder. But I want to use one of the prebuilt images in storyboard. such as:
[image]

How do I go about calling them? is there a way?

Comment: These are SF Symbols. There’s a lot of documentation about them around the internet.

Comment: Code in images can't be copied or searched. Please paste your code instead of including it in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You init the image with its system name:

```swift
let checkImage = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal")
```